# Inno setup+isdone counter timer

Tags: inno-setup

Help modify the time I am not getting much time is left and the elapsed time of installation is appearing on the page status has to appear on the page installing I got here on the site script time can someone check my script and point out the error The script I use isdone more time Sample image of what I want I am not able to post complete script.iss download link full

[enter link description here](http://www.4shared.com/file/KkV7-Wrece/Install.html)

[image]

```
[Code]
////////////////////////////////////ISDONE///////////////////////////
const
  PCFonFLY=true;
  notPCFonFLY=false;
var
  LabelPct1,LabelCurrFileName,LabelTime1,LabelTime2: TLabel;  //Desativa - LabelTime3
  ISDoneProgressBar1: TNewProgressBar;
  MyCancelButton: TButton;
  ISDoneCancel:integer;
  ISDoneError:boolean;
  PCFVer:double;

type
  TCallback = function (OveralPct,CurrentPct: 
integer;CurrentFile,TimeStr1,TimeStr2,TimeStr3:PAnsiChar): longword;

function WrapCallback(callback:TCallback; paramcount:integer):longword;external 
'wrapcallback@files:ISDone.dll stdcall delayload';

function ISArcExtract(CurComponent:Cardinal; PctOfTotal:double; InName, OutPath, 
ExtractedPath: AnsiString; DeleteInFile:boolean; Password, CfgFile, WorkPath: 
AnsiString; 
ExtractPCF: boolean ):boolean; external 'ISArcExtract@files:ISDone.dll stdcall   
delayload';
function IS7ZipExtract(CurComponent:Cardinal; PctOfTotal:double; InName, OutPath: 
AnsiString; DeleteInFile:boolean; Password: AnsiString):boolean; external 
'IS7zipExtract@files:ISDone.dll stdcall delayload';
function ISRarExtract(CurComponent:Cardinal; PctOfTotal:double; InName, OutPath: 
 AnsiString; DeleteInFile:boolean; Password: AnsiString):boolean; external 
'ISRarExtract@files:ISDone.dll stdcall delayload';
function ISPrecompExtract(CurComponent:Cardinal; PctOfTotal:double; InName, OutFile: 
AnsiString; DeleteInFile:boolean):boolean; external 'ISPrecompExtract@files:ISDone.dll 
stdcall delayload';
function ISSRepExtract(CurComponent:Cardinal; PctOfTotal:double; InName, OutFile: 
AnsiString; DeleteInFile:boolean):boolean; external 'ISSrepExtract@files:ISDone.dll 
stdcall delayload';
function ISxDeltaExtract(CurComponent:Cardinal; PctOfTotal:double; 
minRAM,maxRAM:integer; InName, DiffFile, OutFile: AnsiString; DeleteInFile, 
DeleteDiffFile:boolean):boolean; external 'ISxDeltaExtract@files:ISDone.dll stdcall 
delayload';
function ISPackZIP(CurComponent:Cardinal; PctOfTotal:double; InName, OutFile: 
AnsiString;ComprLvl:integer; DeleteInFile:boolean):boolean; external 
'ISPackZIP@files:ISDone.dll stdcall delayload';
function ShowChangeDiskWindow(Text, DefaultPath, SearchFile:AnsiString):boolean; 
external 'ShowChangeDiskWindow@files:ISDone.dll stdcall delayload';

function Exec2 (FileName, Param: PAnsiChar;Show:boolean):boolean; external 
'Exec2@files:ISDone.dll stdcall delayload';
function ISFindFiles(CurComponent:Cardinal; FileMask:AnsiString; var 
ColFiles:integer):integer; external 'ISFindFiles@files:ISDone.dll stdcall delayload';
function ISPickFilename(FindHandle:integer; OutPath:AnsiString; var CurIndex:integer; 
DeleteInFile:boolean):boolean; external 'ISPickFilename@files:ISDone.dll stdcall   
delayload';
function ISGetName(TypeStr:integer):PAnsichar; external 'ISGetName@files:ISDone.dll 
stdcall delayload';
function ISFindFree(FindHandle:integer):boolean; external 'ISFindFree@files:ISDone.dll 
stdcall delayload';
function ISExec(CurComponent:Cardinal; PctOfTotal,SpecifiedProcessTime:double; 
ExeName,Parameters,TargetDir,OutputStr:AnsiString;Show:boolean):boolean; external 
'ISExec@files:ISDone.dll stdcall delayload';

function SrepInit(TmpPath:PAnsiChar;VirtMem,MaxSave:Cardinal):boolean; external 
'SrepInit@files:ISDone.dll stdcall delayload';
function PrecompInit(TmpPath:PAnsiChar;VirtMem:cardinal;PrecompVers:single):boolean; 
external 'PrecompInit@files:ISDone.dll stdcall delayload';
function FileSearchInit(RecursiveSubDir:boolean):boolean; external 
'FileSearchInit@files:ISDone.dll stdcall delayload';
function ISDoneInit(RecordFileName:AnsiString; TimeType,Comp1,Comp2,Comp3:Cardinal; 
 WinHandle, NeededMem:longint; callback:TCallback):boolean; external 
'ISDoneInit@files:ISDone.dll stdcall';
function ISDoneStop:boolean; external 'ISDoneStop@files:ISDone.dll stdcall';
function ChangeLanguage(Language:AnsiString):boolean; external 
'ChangeLanguage@files:ISDone.dll stdcall delayload';
function SuspendProc:boolean; external 'SuspendProc@files:ISDone.dll stdcall';
function ResumeProc:boolean; external 'ResumeProc@files:ISDone.dll stdcall';

function ProgressCallback(OveralPct,CurrentPct: 
integer;CurrentFile,TimeStr1,TimeStr2,TimeStr3:PAnsiChar): longword;
begin
 if OveralPct<=1000 then ISDoneProgressBar1.Position := OveralPct;
  LabelPct1.Caption := IntToStr(OveralPct div 10)+'.'+chr(48 + OveralPct mod 10)+'%';

//  LabelCurrFileName.Caption:='Instalando arquivos.. '+MinimizePathName(CurrentFile, 
LabelCurrFileName.Font, LabelCurrFileName.Width-ScaleX(100));

LabelCurrFileName.Caption:=ExpandConstant('')+MinimizePathName(ExpandConstant('{app}\ 
')+CurrentFile, LabelCurrFileName.Font,WizardForm.FilenameLabel.Width);
  LabelTime1.Caption:=ExpandConstant('{cm:ElapsedTime} ')+TimeStr2;
  LabelTime2.Caption:=ExpandConstant('{cm:RemainingTime} ')+TimeStr1;
//  LabelTime3.Caption:=ExpandConstant('{cm:AllElapsedTime}')+TimeStr3;
  Result := ISDoneCancel;
end;

procedure CancelButtonOnClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SuspendProc;
  if MsgBox(SetupMessage(msgExitSetupMessage), mbConfirmation, MB_YESNO) = IDYES then  
  ISDoneCancel:=1;
  ResumeProc;
end;

procedure HideControls;
begin
  WizardForm.FileNamelabel.Hide;
  ISDoneProgressBar1.Hide;
  LabelPct1.Hide;
  LabelCurrFileName.Hide;
  LabelTime1.Hide;
  LabelTime2.Hide;
  MyCancelButton.Hide;
end;

procedure CreateControls;
var PBTop:integer;
begin
  PBTop:=ScaleY(165); //165
  ISDoneProgressBar1 := TNewProgressBar.Create(WizardForm);
  with ISDoneProgressBar1 do begin
    Parent   := WizardForm;                  //:= WizardForm.InstallingPage;
    Height   := ScaleY(20);                 //WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Height;
    Left     := ScaleX(65);
    Top      := PBTop;
    Width    := ScaleX(470);
    Max      := 1000;
  end;
  LabelPct1 := TLabel.Create(WizardForm);
  with LabelPct1 do begin
    Parent    := WizardForm;
    AutoSize  := true;
    Font.Height:=-25;
    Left      := ISDoneProgressBar1.Left -30 + ISDoneProgressBar1.Width div 2;
    Top       := ISDoneProgressBar1.Top + ScaleY(80);
    Width     := ScaleX(80);
  end;
  LabelCurrFileName := TLabel.Create(WizardForm);
  with LabelCurrFileName do begin
    Parent   := WizardForm;
    AutoSize := False;
    Width    := ISDoneProgressBar1.Width+ScaleX(30);
    Left     := ScaleX(65);
    Top      := ScaleY(140);
    Height   :=ScaleY(25);
//    Font.Color:= clWhite;
    Font.Size:= 10;
  end;
  LabelTime1 := TLabel.Create(WizardForm);
  with LabelTime1 do begin
    Parent   := WizardForm;
    AutoSize := False;
    Width    := ISDoneProgressBar1.Width div 2;
    Left     := ScaleX(65);
    Top      := PBTop + ScaleY(30);
    Height   :=ScaleY(25);
    Font.Size:= 8;
  end;
  LabelTime2 := TLabel.Create(WizardForm);
  with LabelTime2 do begin
    Parent   := WizardForm;
    AutoSize := False;
    Width    := ScaleX(200);
    Left     := Scalex (360); //Original 335 fonte 10
    Top      := LabelTime1.Top;
    Height   :=ScaleY(25);
    Font.Size:= 8;
  end;
//  LabelTime3 := TLabel.Create(WizardForm);
//  with LabelTime3 do begin
//    Parent   := WizardForm;  //FinishedPage para aparecer na ultima pagina 
//    AutoSize := False;
//    Font.Color:= clWhite; //Black
//    Width    := 250;
//    Left     := 10;
//    Top      := 330;
//    Height   :=ScaleY(25);
//    Font.Size:= 8;
//  end;
  MyCancelButton:=TButton.Create(WizardForm);
  with MyCancelButton do begin
    Parent := WizardForm;
    Top := ScaleY(360);
    Left := ScaleX(410);
    Width := ScaleX(90);
    Height := ScaleY(25);
    Caption := 'Cancelar';
    Top:=WizardForm.cancelbutton.top;
    OnClick:=@CancelButtonOnClick;
  end;
end;
////////////////////////////////////CONTADOR/COUNTER/////////////////////////
function GetTickCount: DWORD; external 'GetTickCount@kernel32.dll stdcall';

var
  StartTick: DWORD;
  PercentLabel: TNewStaticText;
  ElapsedLabel: TNewStaticText;
  RemainingLabel: TNewStaticText;

function TicksToStr(Value: DWORD): string;
var
  I: DWORD;
  Hours, Minutes, Seconds: Integer;
begin
  I := Value div 1000;
  Seconds := I mod 60;
  I := I div 60;
  Minutes := I mod 60;
  I := I div 60;
  Hours := I mod 24;
  Result := Format('%.2d:%.2d:%.2d', [Hours, Minutes, Seconds]);
end;

procedure InitializeWizard4();
begin
  PercentLabel := TNewStaticText.Create(WizardForm);
  PercentLabel.Parent    := WizardForm;
  PercentLabel.AutoSize  := true;
  PercentLabel.Font.Height:=-25; //SetBounds(245,220,150,20)
  PercentLabel.Left := ScaleX(245); //esquerda
  PercentLabel.Top := ScaleY(220);  //altura de cima para baixo
  PercentLabel.Width := ScaleX(150);  //comprimento
  PercentLabel.Height := ScaleY(20);  //tamanho

  ElapsedLabel := TNewStaticText.Create(WizardForm);
  ElapsedLabel.Parent   := WizardForm;
  ElapsedLabel.AutoSize := False;
  ElapsedLabel.Font.Size:= 8;  //SetBounds(65,190,150,20)
  ElapsedLabel.Left := ScaleX(65);
  ElapsedLabel.Top := ScaleY(190);
  ElapsedLabel.Width := ScaleX(150);
  ElapsedLabel.Height := ScaleY(20);

  RemainingLabel := TNewStaticText.Create(WizardForm);
  RemainingLabel.Parent   := WizardForm;
  RemainingLabel.AutoSize := False;
  RemainingLabel.Font.Size:= 8; // SetBounds(410,190,150,20)
  RemainingLabel.Left := ScaleX(410);
  RemainingLabel.Top := ScaleY(190);
  RemainingLabel.Width := ScaleX(150);
  RemainingLabel.Height := ScaleY(20);
end;
procedure CurPageChanged5(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
    PercentLabel.Visible := CurPageID = wpInstalling;
    ElapsedLabel.Visible := CurPageID = wpInstalling;
    RemainingLabel.Visible := CurPageID = wpInstalling;
    StartTick := GetTickCount;
end;

procedure CancelButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer; var Cancel, Confirm: Boolean);
begin
  if CurPageID= wpInstalling then
  begin
    Cancel := False;
    if ExitSetupMsgBox then
    begin
      Cancel := True;
      Confirm := False;
      PercentLabel.Visible := False;
      ElapsedLabel.Visible := False;
      RemainingLabel.Visible := False;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure CurInstallProgressChanged(CurProgress, MaxProgress: Integer);
var
  CurTick: DWORD;
begin
  CurTick := GetTickCount;
  PercentLabel.Caption :=
    Format('%.2f %%', [(CurProgress * 100.0) / MaxProgress]);
  ElapsedLabel.Caption :=
    Format('Decorido: %s', [TicksToStr(CurTick - StartTick)]);
  if CurProgress > 0 then
  begin
    RemainingLabel.Caption :=
    Format('Restante: %s', [TicksToStr(
     ((CurTick - StartTick) / CurProgress) * (MaxProgress - CurProgress))]);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Oh, yet another suspicious blackboxed DLL library. All what I can say is that it creates its own progress page and so it doesn't cooperate with the `CurInstallProgressChanged` event (I think so because that event was added quite recently).

Comment: Thanks again TLama summarizing is not possible to change the timer

Comment: Wait, it seems that I'm wrong. Now looking at the script more closely, the plugin does not create its own page, but it uses controls that you create. And even returns overall percent value in its callback. Well, if that is so, then you can use the existing installation progress bar for that plugin. Just consider the following. There are two events that updates the progress state with time values, Inno Setup's `CurInstallProgressChanged` event and that plugin's callback where both are independent. You would have to set the `StartTick` when you start unpacking or what that plugin does...

Comment: ...and modify the overall progress bar position so that it will be e.g. in the half when unpacking finishes and start from that half when Inno Setup starts its installation (if you're asking for how to make from those two independent actions one progress). But sorry, unless you provide a link to the source code for that library, I won't help since I'm considering this library as suspicious.

Comment: No, no. I need a link to the source code of isdone because I don't want to work with a blackboxed DLL (even if antivirus checks would claim it is safe). You know, putting something *evil* into a DLL which will be called (most of the time) from elevated setup process would be great to get control over anything you want. I'm not saying there is something *evil* inside, I'm just saying I do not trust it unless it is published as open source.

Comment: TLama only link to the script http://www.4shared.com/file/KkV7-Wrece/Install.html

Comment: Gotta run LabelTime1 LabelTime2 error in identify (CurProgress) * (MaxProgress)  LabelTime1.Caption:=Format('Decorido: %s', [TicksToStr(CurTick - StartTick)]);;
  LabelTime2.Caption:=Format('Restante: %s', [TicksToStr(((CurTick - StartTick) / CurProgress) * (MaxProgress - CurProgress))]);

Comment: I need something like this example
(Var CurProgress, MaxProgress: Integer)
has with this but the error (Var CurProgress, MaxProgress: Integer)

Answer (score 0):

You gonna have to change your `ISDoneInit "$F777"` to `"$1111"`

It's something like this

```
if ISDoneInit(ExpandConstant('{src}\records.inf'), $1111, Comps1,Comps2,Comps3, MainForm.Handle, 512, @ProgressCallback) then
   begin
```

and you don't have to add a another time count function to get this...just remove it...